# Copy "Distinct" (Text) Values to Clip Board VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Normally when I need to have distinct (non-duplicated values) using for SUMIFS, I just copy the whole column to another sheet/range and use "Removes Duplicates" function.

I wish I could just right click on the range of a column and select "Copy Distinct Values". When I copy and paste, only non-duplicated values pasted.

In other words/way, on the "Paste Options" - there is another function call "Paste Distinct"

The important step is to get the distinct values which I am having problem.
I could do the long way by create a "temp sheet" to store all of the values and remove the duplicates and then copied them to clip board. However, I am avoiding this.

Comment: Best way to learn is to roll up your sleeves and try it on your own first and post back if there is a specific place where you're getting stuck.  I'd start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg469862(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: I have no problem to add customized menu - the problem comes from "distinct" - thanks for the link. I actually started to do the customized the menu a few days ago using that links.

Comment: Have you thought about using a Dictionary object http://www.techbookreport.com/tutorials/vba_dictionary.html?  That would give you an in memory collection of unique values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have the creation of the customized menu down, here's my stab at creating an in-memory collection of unique values and exporting them to another part of the worksheet.  You'll have to modify this code to suit your particular situation, but hopefully it will get you going in the right direction.

It's important to note that you will need to set a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime for this to work (that's where the Dictionary object lives):

```
Sub test()

Dim dictValues       As New Dictionary
    Dim i            As Long
    Dim sheetValues  As Variant
    Dim exportValues As Variant
    Dim joinedValues As String

    sheetValues = Sheet1.Range("A1").Resize(Sheet1.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row, 2)

    For i = 1 To UBound(sheetValues)
        dictValues(sheetValues(i, 1)) = sheetValues(i, 2)
    Next

    exportValues = dictValues.Keys

    Sheet1.Range("B1").Resize(UBound(Application.Transpose(exportValues)), 1) = Application.Transpose(exportValues)

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much. It works as expected. Of course, as you said, I would need to play with it for a quite until I get what I'd like to.  My works focuses primary on finance and my company IT only focus on what they think it's worthy (aka Netflix and management of iSeries IMB400)

Comment: @user2103670 Great, glad I could help out!  Feel free to post back and / or create a new question should you get stuck along the way.  Best of luck with the rest of your project!